# Group students into classes based on friend preferences

Tags: optimization, grouping

Every year the teachers at school need to organise student classes for the following year. Students get to select a number of friends they would like to be with (in order). This may vary but is currently limited to six names. School policy is that each student should be with at least one friend - obviously the more preferred that friend is the better. Given N students each with ranked/weighted preferences of class mates, how can they be optimally partitioned into C classes. Other limiting factors would be:

- Class sizes should be as similar as possible
- Sexes should be reasonably evenly distributed

How would any algorithm be modified to include "cannot be with student X" - assuming a large enough negative ranking/weighting may provide this?

It would seem like a problem solved best by a computer thereby freeing up time for more valuable tasks. This isn't a coursework problem, rather a real world issue I would be interested in finding and understanding a solution to. I have found many posts on grouping people by preferred group but not preferred ranked group members.

Please advise if this is the wrong forum.